# Can I use QFile to truncate a write protected file?

Tags: c++, linux, qt, qprocess, qfile

I am not running the application itself as root.

Rather than do a convoluted

```sh
pkexec sh -c 'echo 50 > /sys/devices/system/cpu/intel_pstate/min_perf_pct'
```

With `QProcess`, I would rather simply open `/sys/devices/system/cpu/intel_pstate/min_perf_pct` and truncate a number into it. It would look something like this:

```cpp
QFile f("/sys/devices/system/cpu/intel_pstate/min_perf_pct");
if ( f->open( QIODevice::WriteOnly | QIODevice::Truncate ) ) {
        f->write( QByteArray::number(n) )
};
```

Is there a way to do this without having to start or run any other part of the application as root? 
I am using `pkexec` for sudo prompts.

Thanks.

Comment: You can run command line actions from C++ using the system() call. I'm not sure if that helps you or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is there a way to do this without having to start or run any other part of the application as root?

No. Otherwise that would defeat the whole purpose of the file permission system.

Comment: Why would that defeat the purpose? Temporarily elevating the priveleges of an object in a program does not seem any different than just running sudo for a function.

Comment: @Jannies-Theydoitforfree: Because once a process has privileged access to a file, it can do all sorts of nasty stuff to it. The way `sudo` works is, that it launches a completely independent process, that itself is protected from any interference of the process that started it. `sudo` works by having the `sudo` binary itself set SUID=0, i.e. that whoever launches it, `sudo` itself will run with root permissions. However in doing so it *must* be very carefully written and not have any exploitable bugs, otherwise this would compromiuse the security of the system.

Comment: @Jannies-Theydoitforfree: There is a way to get an actual file descriptor (that'd be usable with QFile) into an unprivileged process, but this, too involves the help of an outside, auxiliary SUID program. The mechanism is called "file descriptor passing", which operates through a Unix Domain Socket. – And before you ask: No, you definitely should not write such a helper program, that's SUID root and will implement FD passing on arbitrary files.